# Ordering based on number value in a string from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these CB1-15 values however I want to order them by... CB1-15 but currently it goes CB1, CB10, CB11 etc.

This is how my table looks...

```
CB    Description   File Path

CB1   New Product   new.png
CB10            
CB11            
CB12            
CB13            
CB14            
CB15            
CB2   Best Seller   best.png
CB3         
CB4         
CB5         
CB6         
CB7         
CB8         
CB9
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Just so I'm clear.  is the sample data one column or multiple?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti it's been answered - however if anyone searches it later on iv'e updated the post to show its columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below script.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM  YourTable
  ORDER BY CAST(Replace(YourColumn,'CB','')as INT)
```

Comment: Thank you :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear if that data is in multiple columns or a single string.  Here's one method that should work in both cases:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by cast((substring(yourfield, 3, 2)) as int)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1af6d/1)

The key is using `cast` to `order by` an `int` instead of the string.

Comment: Thank you ever so much sir :)

Comment: This doesn't work for CB100 so you have to use the length of value instead of 2 by replacing CB, So I would say @Unnik's solution work better.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method do do the ordering:

```
order by len(col), col
```

And if you want descending:

```
order by len(col) desc, col desc
```